# R graphical output issues: "ghost" plots and malformed PDF files

Tags: r, pdf, plot, ggplot2, rstudio

As a part of my dissertation research, I wrote `R` code that performs a basic *exploratory data analysis (EDA)* of initial datasets. The code is supposed to output the results of EDA in **three formats**: 1) *screen* (RStudio Plots window); 2) *SVG files* (single file per plot); 3) *PDF file* (one file for all univariate EDA plots and another one for all multivariate EDA plots). It is still a work in progress in terms of covering all variables of interest and their relationships, but the basic infrastructure has already been designed and implemented (using `ggplot2` and `gridExtra` packages). I am experiencing the following two **issues** with this:

1) When, during EDA, the code is supposed to display a current plot in the RStudio Plots window, the screen just blinks and **no output** is performed. The following is the **code** that **generates and displays plots** (*screen and SVG only*, see below for PDF output) [similar blocks of code are wrapped in functions, returning plot objects (`g`), which form a list, which, in turn, is passed to `lapply()` for iterating through all plots]:

```
df$var <- factor(df[[colName]])

title <- paste("Projects distribution across", colName, "range")

g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=var, fill=var)) +
  geom_bar(stat="bin") +
  scale_fill_discrete(colName) + 
  xlab(colName) +
  ylab("Number of projects") +
  ggtitle(label=title)

if (.Platform$GUI == "RStudio") {print(g); dev.off()}

edaFile <- str_replace_all(string=colName, pattern=" ", repl="")
edaFile <- paste0(EDA_RESULTS_DIR, "/", edaFile, ".svg")
suppressMessages(ggsave(file=edaFile, plot=g))
```

2) After attempting to open PDF file with EDA results, it opens, but further attempts to navigate it (i.e., line or page scrolling) or otherwise work with it (i.e., change zoom level) **result in hanging of a PDF reader program** (Adobe Reader XI) with message in its title bar "... (Not Responding)". Sometimes, after quite a while, Adobe Reader returns back to the *responsive state*, but for a short period of time, until next action sends its again to the *hanging state*. I noticed that it takes time for Adobe Reader to display one particular plot, specifically a `Q-Q` plot. Just wanted to mention this, as it might give additional insight. The following is the **code** that **outputs saved plots to a PDF file** (these are the same plots that were saved and displayed on the screen as well as were output to SVG files, as described above):

```
edaFilePDF <- paste0(EDA_RESULTS_DIR, "/", "eda-univar.pdf")
mg <- do.call(marrangeGrob, c(allPlots, list(nrow=2, ncol = 1)));
suppressMessages(ggsave(filename=edaFilePDF, mg, width=8.5, height=11))
```

**Your help is much appreciated!** P.S. I use **RStudio Server**, so the output is browser-based.

Comment: 1) I've also noticed problems with graphs in RStudio when a script creates many of them. I never bothered to file a bug report. Sometimes I've used `Sys.sleep`, which seemed to help. 2) The PDF is a vector graphic, which means each object has to be "rendered" by the PDF viewer. If the plots contain many objects (points, lines, ...) it can take a long time for the viewer to process it, which results in the problem. Solutions involve reducing the number of printed points (e.g., by downsampling or using hexbin graphs) or using a pixel graphics format.

Comment: @Roland: I appreciate your fast feedback! Just tried your advice on using `Sys.sleep()`, but it didn't help (I've tried both 1 and 3 seconds delay between iterations). In regard to PDF, your comment makes total sense and explains well my observation related to a `Q-Q` plot. By the way, what the best (optimal) type of plot could you recommend for (instead of) bar graph for a factor with many (48) levels?

Comment: How about running your script directly in `R`? That may avoid some `RStudio`-related hiccups.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I do run most of my scripts via CLI. And, surely, I can run this one, too. But, the idea of running it in RStudio is to see generated plots right away, especially considering the above-mentioned issues with generated PDFs. Also, since I don't have a GUI installed on my EC2 development server, using browser-based RStudio Server seemed to be the optimal solution...